# A message sent to JMS Queue will be consumed by only a single consumer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

A case where senders are sending messages to a Queue, for example `message1` is sent by `sender1` to a queue. Now a consumer named `consumer1` connects to queue and reads the message `message1`.

There is another consumer named `consumer2`. But the message `message1` is already consumed by `consumer1` so it will not be available for `consumer2`.

When a next message arrives in `queue`, `consumer2` might receive that message if it reads the queue before `consumer1`.

Does it mean that it all is a case whether one consumer reads the queue before the other in order to get the first message available from the `queue`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of a Queue in JMS, messages are sent to one consumer and once ack'd they are gone, the next consumer can get the next message and so on.  This is often referred to as competing consumers or load balancing.  The consumers can share the work as jobs or work items are enqueued which allows for higher throughput when the work associated with the items in the Queue can take significant time.

There are options depending on the messaging broker to make a consumer exclusive such that only that consumer can read messages from the queue while the other consumers sit and wait for the exclusive consumer to leave which makes them backups of a sort.

Other options are to use something like Apache Camel to route a given message to more than one queue, or to use AcitveMQ Virtual Topics to send messages to a Topic and have that message then enqueue onto specific consumer Queues.

The solution depends on the broker you are using and the problem you are trying to solve, none of which you've really made clear in the question.

Comment: Actually i was just curious that if a queue message will be consumed by only one consumer then why a queue can be accessed by multiple consumers? What benefit it will give us? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Because it's a Queue and that's what they are defined to do, read the JMS specification if you are still confused.

Comment: @muasif80 to handle load, if you have 100k messages coming in in a few seconds it might help to have multiple consumers that do the same thing.